# More about params of generateTreeList function in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, tree

I'm using Tree in cakephp, but when i use "generateTreeList" function, i don't know clearly about params of this function. Please tell me more about them. Many thanks !

PS/: I see somebody using "{n}.Category.name" for keyPath or valuePath, is "{n}." removable ? or can be replace by another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common practice in this case is to lookup the documentation. That is something pretty normal in a developers every day work.

- http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-TreeBehavior.html#_generateTreeList
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html#TreeBehavior::generateTreeList

No, {n} is used for lists of records like 0.Post.title, 1.Post.title... and so on.

Comment: it mean i can replace {n} -> 0 or 1 or so on ?